# I want to implement a filterPost in my react blogs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to implement a filterPost using react and react Redux in my blog post, but when I try to implement a function where user click to list the post in the filter array, I'm getting which I have tried find a possible way about it. But I'm still getting the same error. Probably bc I still a beginner in react trying to solidify my knowledge about it.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    topics: [
      { id: 1, title: "An Introduction to React", category: "React" },
    ],
    filterPosts: [],
  };

const searchSlice = createSlice({
    name:"topic",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        filterTopics(state, action){
            state.filterPosts = state.topics.filter((post)=>post.category === action.payload)
        }
    }
})

export const {filterTopics} = searchSlice.actions

export default searchSlice.reducer
```

This is the search details.

```
import React from 'react'

export default function SearchDetails({categoryChangeHandler,currentCategory}) {
    const {topics} = useSelector(state=>state.search)
    console.log(topics)

    const categories = []
    
    topics.map(post=>categories.push(post.category))

    const categoryFinal = ["All categories", ...new Set(categories)]

  return (
    <ul className="list-group">
      {categoryFinal.map((category) => (
        <li
          key={category}
          className={
            category === currentCategory
              ? "list-group-item active"
              : "list-group-item"
          }
          onClick={() => categoryChangeHandler(category)}
        >
          {category}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { useState } from 'react'
import searchPost from '../../store/search-post'
import SearchDetails from './SearchDetails'

export default function SearchFilter() {
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState(false)
    const [currentCategory, setCurrentCategory ] = useState("")
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const categoryHandlerChanger = (category) =>{
        setCurrentCategory(category)
        if(category === "All category"){
            setFilter(false)
        
        }else{
            dispatch(filterTopics(category))
            setFilter(true)
        }
    }
  return (
    <div>

        <searchPost filter={filter}/>
        <SearchDetails 
        currentCategory={currentCategory}
        categoryHandlerChanger={categoryHandlerChanger}

        />
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
export default function SearchPost({filter}) {
    const {topics} = useSelector(state=>state.search)
    const {filterTopics} = useSelector(state=>state.search)

    console.log(topics)
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{filter ? filterTopics.length : topics.length} of the {topics.length} posts</p>
      {!filter && topics.map((post)=>(
        <article key={post}>
            {post.title}

        </article>
      ))}

{filter && filterTopics.map((post)=>(
        <article key={post}>
            {post.title}

        </article>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
SearchDetails.js:26 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: categoryChangeHandler is not a function
    at onClick (SearchDetails.js:26:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:9288:1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `SearchFilter`, you are passing down the function as `categoryHandlerChanger` but the `SearchDetails` expect `categoryChangeHandler`

handlerChanger vs changeHandler :)